# Не удаляется последняя строка в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010

Есть кнопка delete при нажатии которой удаляется выделенная строка. Если в таблице больше одной строки, то проблем с удалением нету, однако когда остается последняя строка, то вылетает(см. фото ошибки). Вылетает именно на 
`ui.table->removeRow(oldRow);`
причем при отладке oldRow = 0 и даже пытался вместо него вставить currentRow(), но возникает та же ошибка.

```
//Находим позицию удаляемой записи
int oldRow = ui.table->currentRow();

//Удаляем строку с записью из браузера
QTableWidgetItem *it;
it = ui.table->takeItem(oldRow, 0);
it = ui.table->takeItem(oldRow, 1);
delete it;
ui.table->removeRow(oldRow);
```

пробовал даже так

```
//Находим позицию удаляемой записи
int oldRow = ui.table->currentRow();

//Удаляем строку с записью из браузера
ui.table->removeRow(oldRow);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ui не обьект, а указатель на окно ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение заключается в следующем коде

```
if(oldRow==0 && count == 1)
    //убираем выделение строки
    ui.table->selectionModel()->clearSelection();

//удаляем строку
ui.table->removeRow(oldRow);
```

Дело в том что по какой-то причине, когда единственная строка в table выделена, то выдает ошибку при попытке ее удалить. Когда она не выделена, ошибок нет. Предполагаю что когда строка единственная выделена, то он ищет какую еще строку выделить и получает -1 что и выдает ошибку.

Comment: Не самое хорошее решение как по мне. Надо перед удалением проверять, попадает ли индекс удаляемой строки в правильные пределы (`>=0 && < rowCount()`) и потом или удалять, или делать что-то еще, по ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, почему ваш вариант не работает, возможно, что на момент вызова `removeRow` в таблице уже нет строк по каким-то причинам. Проверьте это в отладчике.

Если дело не в этом - должен сработать такой вариант:

```
if(ui.table->rowCount() <= 1)
  ui.table->setRowCount(0);
else
  ui.table->removeRow(ui.table->currentRow())
```

Comment: Попробовал такой вариант раньше и сейчас. На строке ui.table->setRowCount(0); он падает. То есть он падает когда устанавливаешь количество строк нуль. Пробовал даже когда много списков и при нажатии кнопки удалить вызывается ui.table->setRowCount(0); но все равно вылетает.

Comment: Заметил следующие:
Когда строка не выделена - удаляет.
Когда выделена - выдает ошибку.